# How to get the unix timestamp for "the_date"

Tags: php, wordpress

How can one get the unix timestamp of a published post ("the_date" or "the_time" functions) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pass in the Epoc parameter. `the_time()` will output the string; `get_the_time()` will return it into a variable for use elsewhere.

```
$timestamp = get_the_time('U');
```

Answer (score -5):

As simple as :

```
$unixTimestamp = time();
```

Comment: -1. That will return the **current** time of the request, not the timestamp of the Wordpress post!